# Binary file not executable

Tags: linux, software-installation

I'm trying to install a program, with extension `*.linux64`. I'm using a linux machine with x86-64 architecture.

However, when I run `./program.linux64`, I receive:

```
./program.linux64: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

I changed the file permissions to `chmod 777` thinking that the problem were the permission, thus now with `ls -l`, I have:

```
-rwxrwxrwx .... program.linux64
```

But I still have the same error; how can I install this program?

NOTE: the file is not compressed (I cannot unzip or tar it)

UPDATE (from comments):

Running `file` on it says it's "data":

```
$ file program.linux64
program.linux64: data
```

Running `hexdump -C program.linux64 | head -8`, it returns:

```
00000000  81 29 7f 72 43 3a 5e a3  63 33 67 5e 25 7a 2a 64  |.).rC:^.c3g^%z*d|
00000010  36 94 75 44 b2 c0 56 6b  67 91 5e 33 0a fa 24 b9  |6.uD..Vkg.^3..$.|
00000020  c0 f1 dc 46 af 67 76 dc  d7 d4 1a 72 3f c8 65 fe  |...F.gv....r?.e.|
00000030  6f 47 90 d8 88 ce ae dd  01 8f 79 c9 3e 10 c8 f2  |oG........y.>...|
00000040  27 43 52 b6 2d 4e ab 4b  c3 93 10 1a 6a 5d 5c 5a  |'CR.-N.K....j]\Z|
00000050  3c 33 1a 37 5b 4f e7 00  30 95 1c 4b 10 a4 8d eb  |<3.7[O..0..K....|
00000060  56 fe ef 8c 7b a5 ca aa  65 bd 34 bf f0 e8 30 af  |V...{...e.4...0.|
00000070  9f 32 c9 6e 96 a4 9b ed  87 11 1e f9 94 3b b4 9c  |.2.n.........;..|
```

Comment: What does `file program.linux64` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt program.linux64: data

Comment: There's little hope if even `find` doesn't recognize it. But you could try adding the output of `hd program.linux64 | head -8` to your question, maybe someone could give you a hint (Notice:  `| head -8` instead of `-n128` since the first page may be all zeros)

Comment: @mosvy I don't know why but I don't have the `hd` command in the machine. I update the question with the result of `hexdump -C program.linux64 | head -8`

Comment: Is this a firmware image of some kind?

Comment: @Kusalananda for what I know it's not a firmware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `file` says it's data (you've posted in a comment that it does), it basically means that it's not a file that `file` recognises, especially it's not an executable or compressed with an known (to `file`) algorithm. You'll have to go back to where you got that file and see if they have any instructions.